# Does Azure App Service (Web App) provides SSL/TLS termination?

Tags: azure, nginx, ssl, azure-web-app-service

I'm using an Azure App Service (multi-docker) setup to run a simple web app: NGINX + DJANGO.

Is there a feature/setting in App Service to enable automatic SSL termination? The domain is a default one: `<subdomain>.azurewebsites.net`

I would want to avoid Nginx configuration changes and performing the TSL offloading there, also it would be good to keep the domain, I don't need a custom one.

Answer (score 0):

No, if you want such a thing you should place Azure Front Door/Azure Application Gateway in front of the App Services.

Answer (score 0):

In App Service, TLS termination happens at the frontend load balancer. There are no settings that you can change.